# ¿como puedo pasar una funcion a multiples selected en un archivo HTML?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un curso en JavaScript y tengo el siguiente problema:

En el mismo archivo html tengo una función y a su vez el código html que consta de una serie de opciones las cuales me permite seleccionar día, mes y año, se ejecuta bien sin ningún problema en el navegador.

Mi problema radica a la hora de separar los códigos, y al querer ejecutar el código JavaScript desde un archivo externo, no se como invocar la función dentro de los `selected`, tal cual se hace de manera correcta cuando todo esta dentro de un mismo archivo.

he tratado de crear un archivo con `createElement`, pero no me funciona igual y estoy mal por eso acudo a ustedes para que me ayuden por favor.

Dejo un codepen del archivo para una mejor compresión del mismo.

https://codepen.io/Tony_85/pen/WgMjPz

Saludos y gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Necesitas crear la funcion en un archivo externo en incluir ese archivo en todos los documentos que lo necesites.

Comment: Hola ya lo enlace, lo que me falla es ¿que debo poner dentro de los selected para que se ejecute el código de la función?

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo igual que lo hiciste en el codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esto podrías por ejemplo incluir en la función una variable que le pase el elemento del `DOM` que se va a actualizar. Una vez hecho esto, dentro de la función guardas en una variable dicho elemento, y en la parte en la que escribes en el document, lo sustituyes por este elemento.

Te dejo como lo resolvería yo (he cambiado el método `write()` por `innerHTML` ya que introduces código HTML).
Añado a las variables que pasas a la funcion una llamada select que contiene una cadena con el id del elemento donde introducir la información. Dentro de la función guardo el elemento del id en una variable con `document.getElementById(idelemento)` y a la hora de escribir ejecuto la función innerHTML sobre ese elemento para que inserte HTML dentro de los nodos de ese elemento.

```js
var dia = document.getElementById("dia");

misOpciones(1,31,"dia");
misOpciones(1,12,"mes");
misOpciones(1900, 2050, "anio", 1980);

function misOpciones (desde,hasta,select,selected){
  var select = document.getElementById(select);
  for (let i = 0; i < (hasta - desde+1); i++){
  if (selected != undefined) {
    if (selected === (i + desde)) {
      select.innerHTML += "<option selected='selected'>"+ (i + desde) +"</option>";
    }else{
      select.innerHTML += "<option>"+ (i + desde) +" </option>";
    }
  } else{
    select.innerHTML += "<option>"+ (i + desde) +" </option>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Fecha de nacimiento</p>
<form action="">
  <select name="dia" id="dia" ></select>
  <select name="mes" id="mes"></select>
  <select name="anio" id="anio"></select>    
</form>
```

He cambiado también la forma en la que presentabas los número simplemente sumando la `i` del for y la variable `desde`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me ha servido bastante, algo asi tenia en mente en como resolver el problema pero no tenia muy claro la lógica, ademas tenia dudas con el document.write y ahora que me dices que es mejor el innerHTML me doy cuenta de que esa propiedad es mucho mejor usarla que la otra.

Gracias.